# C++ errors with template friend classes and

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Im creating my own doubly linked list program (I know there is a list library).  I have my main.cc with just my main function that provides a menu to choose the various options for my program and call the correct functions/objects.  I then have 3 different header files containing class files, 1 is the general file for my doubly linked list functions, another is to turn the general DLL functions into queue functions and the last one is to convert the DLL functions to stack functions.

main.cc

```
#include <iostream>


#include "doubly-linked-list.h"
#include "DLLstack.h"
#include "DLLqueue.h"

using namespace std
int choice=0,choice2=0;

int main()
{
    int choice=0,choice2=0,i=0;
    DoublyLinkedList<int> lst;
    DLLstack stlist;
    while(1)
    {

        choice2=0;
        //ask user
        cout<<"\n1. Create Simple (Unsorted) List\n2. Create Sorted List\n";
        cout<<"3. Create LIFO Queue\n4. Create FIFO Queue(Stack)\n";
        cout<<"5. Exit Program\n";
        cout<<"Please choose an option\n";
        cin>>choice;

        while(choice==1)
        {

            //ask user 1.a
            cout<<"\n1. Enter integer for insertion at head of list\n2. Enter integer for insertion at tail of list\n";
            cout<<"3. Display and Delete integer at head\n4. Display and Delete integer at tail\n";
            cout<<"5. Search for integer in list and delete that node\n6.  Display Contents of list from head to tail in order\n7.  Exit\n";
            cout<<"Please choose an option\n";
            cin>>choice2;

            if(choice2==1)//1.1
            {cout<<"Enter integer to add to head\n";
                cin>>i;
                lst.addToDLLHead(i);
            }
            if(choice2==2)//1.2
            {
                cout<<"Enter integer to add to tail\n";
                cin>>i;
                lst.addToDLLTail(i);
            }
            if(choice2==3)//1.3
            { try{
                i=lst.deleteFromDLLHead ();
            } catch(int error_code)
                {
                    cerr<<"Error: "<<error_code<<endl;
                    switch(error_code)
                    {cout<<"Empty List\n";
                            return(1);
                    }
                }

                cout<<"The deleted int was "<<i<<endl;
            }
            if(choice2==4)//1.4
            { try{
                i=lst.deleteFromDLLTail ();
            } catch(int error_code)
                {
                    cerr<<"Error: "<<error_code<<endl;
                    switch(error_code)
                    {case 1:
                        cout<<"Empty List\n";
                            return(1);
                    }
                }
                cout<<"The deleted int was "<<i<<endl;
            }
            if(choice2==5)//1.5
            {
                cout<<"Enter Integer to search for and delete"<<endl;
                cin>>i;
                try{
                    lst.searchdelete (i);
                } catch(int error_code)
                {
                    cerr<<"Error: "<<error_code<<endl;
                    switch(error_code)
                    {cout<<"Empty List\n";
                            return(1);
                    }
                }
            }
            if(choice2==6)
            {lst.printlist ();}
            if(choice2==7) choice=0;
        }





        while(choice==2)
        {
            //ask user 2.b
            cout<<"\n1. Enter integer for sorted insertion(increasing order) into list\n2. Display and delete integer if present in list\n";
            cout<<"3. Display contents of sorted list of integers, in increasing order\n";
            cout<<"4. Exit program\n";
            cout<<"Please choose an option\n";
            cin>>choice2;

            if(choice2==1)//2.1
            {cout<<"Enter integer to add to the sorted list"<<endl;
                cin>>i;
                lst.addSorted (i);
            }
            if(choice2==2)
            {
                cout<<"Enter Integer to search for and delete"<<endl;
                cin>>i;
                try{
                    lst.searchdelete (i);
                } catch(int error_code)
                {
                    cerr<<"Error: "<<error_code<<endl;
                    switch(error_code)
                    {cout<<"Empty List\n";
                            return(1);
                    }
                }
            }
            if(choice2==3)
            {lst.printlist ();}
            if(choice2=4)
            {choice=0;}
        }






        while(choice==3)
        {
            cout<<"\n1. ENQUEUE\n2. DEQUEUE\n";
            cout<<"3. Print QUEUE\n";
            cout<<"4. Exit program\n";
            cout<<"Please choose an option\n";
            cin>>choice2;
            DLLQueue.qlst;

            if(choice2==1)
            {
                cout<<"Enter number to place in Queue"<<endl;
                cin>>i;
                qlst.enqueue(i);}
            if(choice2=2)
            {try{qlst.dequeue();
            } catch(int error_code)
                {
                    cerr<<"Error: "<<error_code<<endl;
                    switch(error_code)
                    {cout<<"Empty List\n";
                            return(1);
                    }
                }
            }
            if(choice2=3)
            {lst.printlist ();}
            if(choice2=4)
            {choice=0;}


        }

            while(choice==4)
            {
                cout<<"\n1. Push\n2. Pop\n";
                cout<<"3. Print STACK\n";
                cout<<"4. Exit program\n";
                cout<<"Please choose an option\n";
                cin>>choice2;
                if(choice2==1)
                {cout<<"Please enter value to place in stack"<<endl;
                    cin>>i;
                    stlst.push(i);
                }
                if(choice2==2)
                {stlst.pop();}
                if(choice2==3)
                {lst.printlist ();}
                if(choice2==4)
                {choice=0;}
            }






        } //original while

        return 0;
    }
```

doubly-linked-list.h

```
#ifndef DOUBLY_LINKED_LIST
#define DOUBLY_LINKED_LIST
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int EMPTY_LIST=1;
template<class T>
class DLLNode
{
    friend class DoublyLinkedList;
    friend class DLLQueue;
    friend class DLLstack;
public:
    DLLNode(){next=prev=NULL;}
    DLLNode(const T& el, DLLNode *n=NULL, DLLNode *p=NULL)
{info=el;
    next=n;
    prev=p;
}
T info;
DLLNode<T> *next, *prev;
protected:
//T info;
//DLLNode<T> *next, *prev;
private:

};

template<class T>
class DoublyLinkedList
{
    friend class DLLQueue;
    friend class DLLstack;
public:
    DoublyLinkedList() {head=tail=NULL;} //good
    void addToDLLTail(const T&); //good
    T deleteFromDLLTail(); //good
    T isDLLEmpty() {return (head==NULL);} //good
    void addToDLLHead(const T&); //added
    T deleteFromDLLHead(); //added
    void deleteDLLNode(const T&); //added
    bool isInList(const T&) const; //added
    void addSorted(const T&); //added
    void printlist(); //added
    T searchdelete(const T&);


protected:

private:
DLLNode<T> *head, *tail;
};

template<class T>
T DoublyLinkedList<T>::deleteFromDLLTail(){
    if(head!=NULL){
        T el=tail->info;
        if(head==tail){
            delete tail;
            head=tail=NULL;
        }
        return el;
    }
    else throw(EMPTY_LIST);
}

template<class T>
void DoublyLinkedList<T>::addToDLLTail(const T& el) {
    if(tail!=NULL){
        tail=new DLLNode<T>(el,NULL,tail);
        tail->prev->next=tail;
    }
    else head=tail= new DLLNode<T>(el);
}

template<class T>
void DoublyLinkedList<T>::addToDLLHead (const T& el) {
    head = new DLLNode<T>(el,head);
    if(tail==NULL) tail=head;
}

template<class T>
T DoublyLinkedList<T>::deleteFromDLLHead (){
    if(head!=NULL)
    {
        int el=head->info;
        DLLNode<T> *tmp=head;
        if(head==tail)
        {head=tail=NULL;}
        else{head=head->next;}
        delete tmp;
        return(el);
        }
    else throw(EMPTY_LIST);
}

template<class T>
void DoublyLinkedList<T>::deleteDLLNode(const T& el) {  
if(head!=NULL){
   if(head==tail&&el==head->info) {
       delete head;
       head=tail=NULL;
   }
   else if(el==head->info){
       DLLNode<T> *tmp=head;
       head=head->next;
       head->prev=NULL;
       delete tmp;
   }
   else {
       DLLNode<T> *pred, *tmp;
       for(tmp=head->next;tmp!=NULL && tmp->info!=el;tmp=tmp->next);
       if(tmp!=NULL){
           pred=tmp->prev;
           pred->next=tmp->next;
           pred->next->prev=pred;

       if(tmp==tail) {tail=tail->prev;}
           delete tmp;
       }
   }
}
else throw(EMPTY_LIST);
}

template<class T>
bool DoublyLinkedList<T>::isInList(const T& el) const {
    DLLNode<T> *tmp;
    for(tmp=head;tmp!=NULL&&tmp->info !=el; tmp=tmp->next);
    return (tmp !=NULL);
}

template<class T>
void DoublyLinkedList<T>::addSorted(const T& i) {
    DLLNode<T> *tmp, *nxt;
    for(tmp=head;tmp->info<i;tmp=tmp->next);
    nxt=tmp->next;
    tmp->next= new DLLNode<T> (i,nxt,tmp);
    next->prev=tmp->next;
    delete tmp;
    delete nxt;
}

template<class T>
void DoublyLinkedList<T>::printlist() {
    DLLNode<T> *tmp;
    if(head!=NULL){
    for(tmp=head;tmp->next!=NULL;tmp=tmp->next){
        cout<<tmp->info<<endl;
    }
    }
}

template<class T>
T DoublyLinkedList<T>::searchdelete(const T& i)
{ DLLNode<T> *tmp;
    for(;tmp->info!=i&&tmp!=NULL;tmp=tmp->next){}
        delete DLLNode<T> (tmp);
    return(cout<<"Value Deleted from List\n");
}



#endif // DOUBLY_LINKED_LIST
```

DLLstack.h

```
#ifndef _DLLSTACK_H_
#define _DLLSTACK_H_
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "doubly-linked-list.h"
class DLLstack
{
    friend class<class T> DoublyLinkedList;
    friend class<class T> DLLNode;
public:
    DLLstack(){};
    bool isEmpty() const
{return lst.isEmpty();}
    void clear()
{
    while(!list.isEmpty()){
        lst.deleteFromDLLHead();}
}
int pop()
{return (lst.deleteFromHead();}
void push(const int& el);
{lst.addToDLLHead (el);}
int topEl()
{
    int topelement;
    topelement=lst.deleteFromDLLHead ();
    lst.addToDLLHead (topelement);
    return(topelement);
}
protected:

private:
DoublyLinkedList stlst;
};

#endif // _DLLSTACK_H_
```

DLLqueue.h

```
#ifndef _DLLQUEUE_H_
#define _DLLQUEUE_H_
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "doubly-linked-list.h"
template<class T>
class DLLQueue
{
    friend <class T> class DoublyLinkedList
    friend <class T> class DLLNode
public:

DLLQueue(){};
bool isEmpty() const
{ return lst.isEmpty();}
void enqueue(const T& el)
{ lst.addToDLLTail (el);}
T dequeue()
{ return {lst.deleteFromDLLHead ();}
T firstEl()
{
    T front_el;
    front_el=lst.deleteFromDLLHead ();
    lst.addToDLLHead (front_el);
    return(front_el);
}
~DLLQueue() {clear();}
protected:

private:
DoublyLinkedList qlst;
};

#endif // _DLLQUEUE_H_
```

Now I get 30 errors, but my main problem (i think) is that it says my friend function declarations in my DLLqueue.h file and DLLstack.h file are
DLLqueue.h:11:9: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
DLLstack.h:11:14: error: expected identifier before ‘<’ token

as well as my lst object in both the stack and queue classes "was not declared in this scope"

doubly-linked-list.h:141:2: error: ‘next’ was not declared in this scope

there are more errors but I think these are causing the major problems and i need to fix these first to continue.

If you are wondering I am programming in the Ajuta IDE in Ubuntu

Comment: Is DoublyLinkedList a template? If so, why do you declare it like this: DoublyLinkedList qlst; ?

Comment: this smells of poorly done homework ... also, before you worry about one in 30 errors, first resolve the other 29 to avoid any confusion these create for the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
friend <class T> class DoublyLinkedList
```

should be

```
template <class U> friend class DoublyLinkedList;
```

or

```
friend class DoublyLinkedList<T>;
```

depending on which instantiations actually need to be friends; and likewise for the other friend declarations.

```
DoublyLinkedList qlst;
```

should be

```
DoublyLinkedList<T> qlst;
```

since `DoublyLinkedList` is a template, not a type.

There's shouldn't be a semicolon before the function body in `DLLStack::push`:

```
void push(const int& el);
{lst.addToDLLHead (el);}
```

You have an unwanted `(` with no matching `)` in `DLLstack::pop`:

```
{return (lst.deleteFromDLLHead();}
```

And an unwanted `{` in `DLLQueue::deque`:

```
{ return {lst.deleteFromDLLHead ();}
```

There are various typos (e.g. declaring a member `stlst` and referring to it variously as `lst` and `list`) - the compiler errors will point you directly at these.

`DoublyLinkedList::isDLLEmpty` needs to be declared `const`, so it can be called from the `const` member functions of the other classes (once you've fixed the typos that call it `isEmpty`).

In `DoublyLinkedList::searchdelete`, `delete DLLNode<T>(tmp)` should just be `delete tmp`. You also need to fix up the pointers in the nodes on either side of the deleted one, and return a value of type `T` (presumably `i`), and fix the behaviour of the loop so it actually searches for the correct node (as it is, it iterates through to the end, then deletes the null pointer, with the result that it does nothing).

Finally, `~DLLQueue` tries to call `DoublyLinkedList::clear` which doesn't exist. You should implement either that, or a destructor for `DoublyLinkedList` (or both). As it is, the list is a memory leak. It should also have a copy constructor and assignment operator (simply declared private if you don't want the class to be copyable).

Also, you shouldn't use reserved names (beginning with an underscore, such as `_DLLQUEUE_H_`) as include guards. You also shouldn't put `using namespace std;` in your header files; the user of the header file might not want the global namespace polluted.

Comment: Anjuta automatically does the names for those when i click add a class file.

Comment: It would be better to change them, or make the IDE generate legal names if that's possible. Otherwise, there's a risk that the names might clash with ones used in the library headers.

Comment: Would you like to me repost my code, i changed a good bit of it as per yours and the other's reccomendations

Answer (score 1):

Change your friend declaration to

```
template <class U> friend class DLLNode;
```

Also semicolons are missing here

```
class DLLQueue
{
    friend <class T> class DoublyLinkedList
    friend <class T> class DLLNode
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't write your own list, stack or queue. Use `std::deque` with `std::stack` and `std::queue` adaptors instead.
2. Don't ever do `using namespace std` in the header.
3. All your friend declarations use wrong syntax. It should be `template <typename T> friend class X;` (or with `class` instead of `typename`). Also, identifiers are case sensitive, `DLLStack` and `DLLstack` are two completely different things.
4. Your classes will not work properly with copying.
5. Don't throw ints, use a proper subclass of `std::exception` instead.
6. You don't use the template arguments in member variable definitions.

I don't see any more major problems, but I might be missing something in all the pointer stuff.

Comment: I really wish I could use std::queue stack etc..., whats wrong with using namespace std?,what do you mean by copying? my teacher specifically told us to throw ints,and by arguments do you mean the <T>'s?

Comment: @WillGunn: Everything is wrong with `using namespace std`, especially in a header. Copying occurs when you pass variables around by value. Your classes will cause double deletes when copied. Yes, <T> is the template argument.

Comment: Re: `const int EMPTY_LIST=1;` in header violates One Definition Rule. No it doesn't - constants have internal linkage unless declared `extern`.